# Received Multipart File by Spring is null

Tags: android, spring, retrofit

I have a File and i want to send it to Spring Backend from Android. After receiving the image at Spring I am changing the name of the Image by Generating the UUID and then uploading it to AWS S3. My problem is i am getting null value as response.

**Android Side ->**

My Android Upload File Function ->

```
private void UploadFiles() {
        File uploadFile = fileArrayList.get(0);
        if (uploadFile != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "UploadFiles: File Name is -> " + uploadFile.getName());

            // cropImageRequest.setCropId(uploadFile.getParentFile().getName());

            // Parsing any Media type file
            RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), uploadFile);

            // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
            MultipartBody.Part cropImage = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("cropImage", uploadFile.getName(), requestFile);

            Api.uploadCropImage(cropImage, new Callback<BasicResponse>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<BasicResponse> call, Response<BasicResponse> response) {
                    if (response.body() != null) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Success" + response.body().getResponse());
                    }
                    else{
                        Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: null Response");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<BasicResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Failure");
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

**uploadImageFunction -> **

```
 public static void uploadCropImage(MultipartBody.Part cropImage, Callback<BasicResponse> callback) {
        UploadCropImageApi uploadCropImageApi = retrofit.create(UploadCropImageApi.class);
        Call<BasicResponse> call = uploadCropImageApi.uploadCropImage(cropImage);
        call.enqueue(callback);
    }
```

My Interface ->

```
public interface UploadCropImageApi {
        @Multipart
        @POST(UPLOAD_FILE_TO_AWS_URL)
        Call<BasicResponse> uploadCropImage(@Part MultipartBody.Part cropImage);
    }
```

This is my Spring File ->

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UploadCropImage", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"multipart/form-data"})
    @ResponseBody
    public String UploadImage(@RequestBody MultipartFile cropImage,HttpServletRequest request) {
        mAmazonClient = AmazonClient.GetAmazonClientInstance();
        UUIDUtils uuid = new UUIDUtils();
        try {
            System.out.println(cropImage);
            String KeyName = uuid.GenerateUUID(cropImage.getName());
            String Code = mAmazonClient.uploadImage(KeyName, cropImage);
            System.out.println(Code);
            return Code;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }
    }
```

This Controller is printing following value ->

```
org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile@b0b5de0
File Name is -: cropImage
null
```

My Problem is that as you can see the file sent by Retrofit and received by Spring is not null, I am sending that file via AWS, but it's not uploading the file and returns null as value. But when i use POSTMAN it's easily sending the file to AWS and returns the KeyName.

**Okay so i debug a little bit and found out an exception while uploading Image file. and the exception is this -> The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

Comment: you say that you get successful requests in POSTMAN but not AWS - is it possible that AWS is not setting some header or property like you think it might be? I know that I've set things up the way I expect in POSTMAN, just to find that I hadn't set those same settings in my actual request.

Comment: @ebernard, i don't think the header can be an issue here, as i am able to fetch the file, but while uploading the file it's unable to do so. which POSTMAN does easily.

Comment: are you using spring boot?

Comment: @slimane, Hello again, i really don't know which version i am using, but it's spring and i know how to declare Rest APIs.

Comment: can check in you pom.xml in there's something like spring boot ....?

Comment: @slimane, yes there are 2 jar files 1 is spring and second one is spring-boot.

Comment: ok, changed RequestBody to RequestParam and remove request if you don't use it, should be like this :
 public String UploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile cropImage)

Comment: @slimane why would Avi use RequestParam for uploading a *body* of content? I'm not sure you can really place a file into the URL, which is where the RequestParams come from, no?

Comment: @AviPatel can you post the text of the Exception that you logged?

Comment: @ebernard RequestParam doesn't only mean queryparam, he is sending data in multipart/form-data so spring will handle that as RequestParam

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception says there is something wrong in your file name. The problem is naming convention as it was uploading file name containing ":" sign and there may be other signs as well which is not accepted by AWS. so, just change file name and separate the names by _(Underscore) sign instead of " "(space), (:) and other signs. This will successfully upload the file to the AWS. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks it turns out that i was using timestamp with (:) and it was generating an exception.